# Transforming array of input to json

Tags: jquery, json

I have a array of input field called phone[], each of these array of input has its own property like office home and mobile ,after the user enters a phone numbers in the fields he will assign each one property such like the attached photo below :

[image]

data retrieved to back-end is `["+962772330223","+962772330223","+962772330223","+962772330223"]`

Now i would like to have this json structure based on what the user chosen   for each phone type noting that default is office .

example

```
phone [{0{office:123,mobile:321}1{mobile:123,office:321}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

First try your problem on Google than post here.

By the way try this:

```
var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(yourArray);
```

Comment: I am asking  about the logic not how to   do json stuff